# How do I access this variable in iOS debugger?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

I have a debugger in this loop :

```
    for view: UIView in containerView.subviews {
        // debugger stops here!
        var rect = CGRectMake(0,contentRect.size.height, self.view.frame.width, view.frame.height)
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, rect)
    }
```

If I run :

```
(lldb) po view
<UILabel: 0x7ff45176f800; frame = (0 0; 11516.5 20.5); text = 'Many translations suggest...'; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7ff45176fa10>>
```

I naturally assume that I could access the `text` attribute via :

```
po view.text
```

But that returns :

```
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: value of type 'UIView' has no member 'text'
```

How can I access this attribute?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same way you would access it in code, you have to cast it, otherwise the debugger still sees `view` as a `UIView` instance:

```
// Swift
po (view as! UILabel).text

// Obj-C
po [(UILabel *) view text]
```

Comment: Ah oh interesting. So my file is in Swift, but debugger only runs in Obj-C?

Comment: @Trip No, sorry, I have not realized you are using Swift. It's the same in Swift, you have to cast it. I will add Swift solution.

Comment: Ah Brilliant! Thanks so much!